# Spring Project - Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find io.micrometer:micrometer-bom:pom:2.0.0-M3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, micrometer

I am getting the following error when I tried to `mvn clean install` on [this spring project](https://github.com/in28minutes/spring-master-class/tree/master/01-spring-in-depth):

```
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact io.micrometer:micrometer-bom:pom:2.0.0-M3 in spring-snapshots (https://repo.spring.io/snapshot) @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.0.0-M2, C:\Users\abc
\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-dependencies\3.0.0-M2\spring-boot-dependencies-3.0.0-M2.pom, line 2273, column 19
```

I am using this basic settings file in my `.m2` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  
  <pluginGroups>
  </pluginGroups>

  <proxies>
  </proxies>

  <servers>
  </servers>

  <mirrors>
  </mirrors>
  
  <profiles>
  </profiles>

</settings>
```

Some of the dependencies are downloading fine (see below), but seems that `micrometer` is causing an issue.

```
Downloading from spring-snapshots: https://repo.spring.io/snapshot/org/springframework/session/spring-session-bom/2022.0.0-M1/spring-session-bom-2022.0.0-M1.pom
Downloading from spring-milestones: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/session/spring-session-bom/2022.0.0-M1/spring-session-bom-2022.0.0-M1.pom
Downloaded from spring-milestones: https://repo.spring.io/milestone/org/springframework/session/spring-session-bom/2022.0.0-M1/spring-session-bom-2022.0.0-M1.pom (2.8 kB at 5.2 kB/s)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please post your pom.xml or build.gradle file with dependencies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Spring Boot 3.0.0-M2 was released, the Micrometer 2.0 release upon which it depends was abandoned and replaced with a backwards-compatible 1.10 release instead. As part of this, to avoid confusion about the latest version, the Micrometer team took the decision to delete the 2.0 artifacts from https://repo.spring.io. An unfortunate consequence of this is that Spring Boot 3.0.0-M2 is no longer usable.

At the time of writing, the latest milestone of Spring Boot 3.0 is 3.0.0-M4. Upgrading to it will resolve your problem. It depends on a Micrometer 1.10 milestone.